# Want to capture data after the search action using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, webdriver

I am working on a ERP application where I have to click on a 'Search' button after which it will give me list of data.

I want to automate that using WebDriver.

[image: Screenshot of ERP application showing Search button and results]

The Search tab is empty before the search option. I want to check whether the data is coming after pressing the 'Search' button or not.

How to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer this link and let us know is this ok for you

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198947/how-to-get-text-from-each-cell-of-an-html-table)